# Orchard CMS "Microsoft Azure Media Storage" module unable to connect to new storage account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, orchardcms

I would like to connect my Orchard CMS v.1.10.1.0 app to an Azure blob storage account. I've followed the same process for years, [following this documentation](https://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Using-Windows-Azure-Blob-Storage/#enabling-for-microsoft-azure-web-sites). This process has stopped working for me. My application won't connect to new Azure storage accounts -- be they StorageV1, StorageV2, or Blob Storage.

I can connect to storage accounts that I have used with Orchard in the past--I just can't connect to new storage accounts.

```
An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.Exists(Boolean primaryOnly, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) at Orchard.Azure.Services.FileSystems.AzureFileSystem.EnsureInitialized() at Orchard.Azure.Services.FileSystems.AzureFileSystem.ListFolders(String path) at Orchard.MediaLibrary.Services.MediaLibraryService.GetMediaFolders(String relativePath) at Orchard.MediaLibrary.Controllers.AdminController.Index(String folderPath, Boolean dialog) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() Request Information RequestID:edaa1946-501e-0035-0d03-9c41ef000000 RequestDate:Tue, 06 Oct 2020 17:10:00 GMT StatusMessage:The TLS version of the connection is not permitted on this storage account.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by putting this line before the call to storage account.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by going into the Configuration settings for the new storage account and requiring a lower minimum TLS version.